# Cant satisfy constrains in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uitableview

I have TableViewCell with [this](http://oi62.tinypic.com/xcoyfs.jpg) prototype.

When user select "No" in segmented control, textView for comment should appear. I have created a QuestionTableViewCell class:

```
class QuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var comment: UITextView!
    // height constraint for comment textView
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    // spacing between segmentedControl bottom and comment textView top
    @IBOutlet weak var spacingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath i set this constrains to satisfy my needs:

```
if questionsAnswers[indexPath.row] == "" || questionsAnswers[indexPath.row] == "YES" {
    comments[indexPath.row] = ""
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = 0.0
    cell.spacingConstraint.constant = 0.0
} else {
    cell.spacingConstraint.constant = 8
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = 70.0
}
```

But when i click "No" in cell's textView i got these constrains collisions:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa28311d030 V:[UITextView:0x7fa2818c1600'Add a note if necessary..'(70)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa283123930 UILabel:0x7fa283119f20'1. Question 1?'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa283119de0.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa283123a20 V:[UILabel:0x7fa283119f20'1. Question 1?']-(NSSpace(8))-[UISegmentedControl:0x7fa28311a8d0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa283123bd0 UITextView:0x7fa2818c1600'Add a note if necessary..'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa283119de0.bottomMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa283123c20 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7fa28311a8d0]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fa2818c1600'Add a note if necessary..']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa280cb4e30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa283119de0(73.5)]>"
```

I think this constraint is breaking the layout:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa280cb4e30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa283119de0(73.5)]>"
```

But i don't know how to fix this( Any ideas how it can be solved?

Comment: Set the cell's `contentView` to stop it from using auto resizing, e.g.: `cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

Comment: i tried this, but the app just freezes when i segueing to my tableViewController

Comment: what is your target IOS, meaning this error occur when you are running which iOS ?

Comment: IOS 8.3, i'm working in emulator for now.

Comment: Could you post the code where you are calculating the cell height? It seems like the cells height is smaller than necessary to satisfy all constraints. It should be at least 86 from what I can read from your constraints

Comment: I just use these two lines of code
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight`
`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
Can u show me an example how to calculate rows height myself?
Because i just use autosize.